# Migrated question using incorrect definition of the site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I [migrated a question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/680/where-can-i-find-sdk-for-the-upcoming-windows-phone-8-release) to StackOverflow but the message that appear there is different from what we are using in the [faq](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/faq).

We are using:

> Stack Exchange is for enthusiasts and power users of Windows Phone OS

But was shown in StackOverflow:

> This question came from our site for enthusiasts and power users of Windows Phone 7.

I mean, we intend to cover all Windows Phone version not only Windows Phone versions 7.